# Does log $f(n) = O($log $g(n))$ imply $f(n) = O(g(n))?$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Assuming log is base 2, if I know that:

log $f(n) = O($log $g(n))$. Does this imply that $f(n) = O(g(n))$?

I understand that the converse is true.

Comment: **Do not** deface or delete the questions you pose after receiving an answer.  Doing so demonstrates a lack of respect towards those that have spent time/effort providing you with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For example, $\log(n^2)=O(\log(n))$.